# Bootstrap. Make vertical browser scrollbar start under fixed navbar. (not overlap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, navbar

I'm using an example code for a fixed navbar provided by bootstrap. Is there any relatively easy way to make a browser scrollbars not overlap a fixed navbar.

Here is how it is in example:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCEVt.png]

Here is what I'm trying to get:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY0km.png]

Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Add relevant code so we can see what your doing.

Comment: To see the code mentioned is this question you can do the following: go to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ and use 'View page source' in browser.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you'll need to make your header a fixed element at the top of the page and use a `position: fixed` container to wrap the rest of the content on your page. Here is an example:

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul><!-- other header elements --></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- All of the content of your site -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I probably doing something wrong, but I was unable to get desired result with you suggestion. Here is what I did:  I took an example web page code (see http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and put whole <nav>...</nav> section inside  <div id="header"><nav>...</nav></div> and the rest of the page into <div id="container">...</div>. I also added your css code to the bottom  of bootstrap.css. But the rendered page still has the navbar overlapped with a scrollbar.

Comment: Did you use the CSS from that page as well? Because that would cause problems with the CSS I've provided.